# week beginning (Monday) for previous day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pull all the data for the week to the previous day.
for example:

if the date was Monday 2016-05-09. I would like the previous Monday 2016-05-02 to Sunday 2016-05-08.

If the date was Tuesday 2016-05-10. I would like the previous Monday 2016-05-09 to Monday 2016-05-09.

I have tried using with no joy.

```
and (ShiftDate Between DATEADD(wk, 0, DATEADD(DAY, (1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()-1)), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())))and GETDATE()-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this:

```
and (ShiftDate Between (GETDATE() - 1 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE() -1) + 7 - 2) % 7)
                       and (GETDATE()-1)
    )
```

Because `Sunday` is 1 in `weekday` so you should add **7** then module by **7** to get the different from nearest `Monday` (2 in `weekday`) to the previous day.

Comment: i am getting an error with this
**The data types datetime and int are incompatible in the modulo operator.**

Comment: @Dan171: Sorry, missing 1 `(`. Editted.